# Shared Tooltip Not Showing Values on Second Yaxis

Tags: highcharts

Here is a representative [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2NXH5/). What I want is that all four data elements appear on the tooltip. Currently the item that is using the secondary yAxis does not show up. If I set this point to use the primary yAxis it still does not show up. It looks like its xAxis "link" is gone - it should be using the same xAxis category value as the other 3.

Code for the tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
            s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ';
            if (point.series.name == 'Unemployment Rate (%)') {
                s += Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2, '.');
            } else {
                s += Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0, ',');
            }
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure will you accept this as an answer but it may give you some ideas. The thing is that Highcharts API says

> When the tooltip is shared, the entire plot area will capture mouse
>   movement. Tooltip texts for series types with ordered data (**not** pie,
>   **scatter**, flags etc) will be shown in a single bubble.

Since your fourth series is exactly `scatter` - it is not available through given formatter. If you are sure that you will have only one point in your chart, you may change series type from `scatter` to `line` to make it work - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NXH5/1/). If you want only `scatter` it won't be easy (or just impossible).

Comment: I always forget the scatter is not like the others. I will talk to BA team to see if they are okay with bar or point (we can have a single element so line type would not make sense in these cases).